# Django bulk_create not setting the field with choices

Tags: python, django

In my model.py file, I have basic and premium coupon like below.

```
coupon_types = (
    ("Basic", "basic"),
    ("Premium", "premium"),
)


class Coupon(Stamp):
    ...
    type = models.CharField(choices=coupon_types, max_length=256, default=coupon_types[0], null=True, blank=True)
```

In the code below, I am trying to create the coupon objects in the database

```
class ClassName:
    ...
    # Some attributes and methods
    ...
    def __construct_initiator_object(self, **kwargs):
        objs = [
            self.initiator(
                ...
                ...
                type=coupon_types[0] if self.coupon_type.lower() == 'basic' else coupon_types[1]
            )
            for code in self.coupons
        ]
        return objs

    @transaction.atomic
    def __create__(self):
        objs = self.__construct_initiator_object()
        create_objs = Coupon.objects.bulk_create(objs)

        return create_objs
```

My problem now is that whenever I call the create method, the bulk_create sets every other field but **not** the **type** field. I don't know if it's because I have the `choices=coupon_types` in the **type** field.
Any help on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you need to change your choices to something like:

```
class Coupon:
    BASIC = "Basic"
    PREMIUM = "Premium"
    coupon_types = (
        (BASIC, "basic"),
        (PREMIUM, "premium"),
        )
    ...
    type = models.CharField(choices=coupon_types, max_length=256, default=BASIC)
```

Also note that I removed `null` and `blank` from this field because you provided default value for this field and you don't need them. Please make sure your database is up to date by running `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

and then change your `__construct_initiator_object` to:

```
def __construct_initiator_object(self, **kwargs):
    objs = [
        self.initiator(
            ...
            ...
            type=Coupon.BASIC if self.coupon_type.lower() == 'basic' else Coupon.PREMIUM
        )
        for code in self.coupons
    ]
    return objs
```

And since I couldn't find your `initiator` method, please make sure that you are adding everything (i.e. type) to objects in that method. Hope this solves your problem.